# Crystal Reports with SQL Server 2005: Setting Transaction Isolation Level

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Is there a way to specify the [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) when Crystal Reports queries a SQL Server 2005 database **without** resorting to any of the following:

- Encapsulating the report's query in a stored procedure that executes `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL...` before the query itself
- Hand-writing the SQL query in Crystal Reports to execute `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL...`

Comment: What are you using to connect to the server? (i.e. ADO.NET via SqlClient, ODBC, OleDb? JDBC? etc.)

Comment: @chadhoc: I am trying to accomplish this via the Crystal Reports application. I am not writing code to use the database connectivity libraries you mentioned. I want Crystal Reports to automatically configure its database connections when **it** uses the database connectivity libraries.

Comment: crap, I was afraid of that - unfortunately, I won't be much help there. I think if you're using ODBC via C.R. that you would have the option of making some registry updates, or creating a DSN on the system that would specify the iso level you want to use, but if you're using anything else (i.e. OleDb, JDBC, etc.) I'm not going to be much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to embed this in a Command object:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ

--Command objects need to return a value
SELECT GetDate()
```

This Command object was *in addition* to the query that I 'wrote' in the Database Expert.

Will you elaborate on the necessity of setting the ISOLATION LEVEL?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will the command execute *before* the real query and in the same connection (transaction isolation levels are on a connection-by-connection basis)? I tried adding this to a new report and Crystal Reports gave me the "Your current link configuration contains multiple starting points" warning, thereby making me wonder which executes first.

Comment: I wish to set the transaction isolation level because one of our reports has a long-running query (~2 minutes) that selects all rows from an often-used table. Because this locks (shared locks) every row in this often-used table, no one else is able to update it until the query completes.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know when it will execute relative to the 'main' query. 

Is this something you can test?

Another thought: perhaps you could create a special account for queries generated by reports and set this accounts isolation level.

Comment: I didn't think transaction isolation levels could be specified on a per-user basis. Do you have an example of how I would configure this for a report-specific user?

Comment: I don't.  I'm not even sure you could do it, but I thought I would mention it as an idea.  A DBA should be able to answer this question.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again, Craig. Wonderful answer!